# Как выполнять код если он в строке

Tags: python, строки

Помогите пожалуйста, мне нужно чтобы код выполнялся, но он в строке, например:
Есть код

```
r = "print("Привет")"
```

И мне нужно чтобы вот код из переменной r выполнялся как обычный код, возможно ли такое сделать?

Comment: eval('print("hello")')

Comment: А можно вопрос - зачем вам это делать? Если у вас нет веских причин так, делать, то лучше отказаться (подсказка: скорее всего таких причин у вас нет)

Comment: Если из чистого интереса, то допустимо

Comment: Просто интересно

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот так:

```
exec('print("hello")')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Здесь стоило бы добавить, что exec нужно использовать очень осторожно, и никогда не применять его к коду, который приходит откуда-то из внешнего источника.

Comment: Вот хорошая статья на хабре, где отлично написано, почему лучше не пользоваться eval (такк сказать, облегченная версия exec): _[И снова про опасность eval()](https://habr.com/ru/post/221937/)_

Answer (score 0):

Также можно использовать одну из функций питона:

```
r = "print(125)"
eval(r) # Или exec(r)
```

Comment: Но лучше не использовать.